# jqgrid select multiple cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way in jqgrid to select multiple cells? Ideally I want to toggle different cells and be able to restrict it in a way that only 1 cell can be toggled on in each row.

Is jqgrid suited for this or should I be using a different library?

Comment: Why you need to select cells instead of rows. jqGrid has internal variables which support of selected rows. If you would implement the selection of multiple cells how you would to use it?

Comment: So I can add the contents of the cell to an array to do further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement reminds me the requirement to select words in the grid instead of rows. You can implement this, but jqGrid could not help you here. On the other side if you select **a row** you can use `Edit` or `Delete` navigator button to remove it. There are internal parameters `selarrrow` and `selrow` which hold the id of the selected row.

If you really need to implement such custom selection you can use [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) or [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event handler to do this. Yon can save the list of selected cells in your custom variable. You can use `.addClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected","true")` for the `<td>` element instead of `<tr>` what jqGrid do. It is important that you will be not able to use any [editing features](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#editing) of jqGrid in the case.